# Convert 4-byte `binary(4)` to an unsigned integer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, binary, integer

I have IPv4 address stored in DB as `VARBINARY(4)`: four bytes of an unsigned integer. Very strange approach, yes :)

How do I convert it to an unsigned integer in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad & slow solution: `CONV(HEX(table.ip),16,10)`